# Dynamical dropdown list with php

Tags: php, html

With PHP i made array like this and i would display dynamic dropdown list menu.

This is PHP array example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [id_subpage] => 0
            [alias] => test
            [title] => Test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [id_subpage] => 1
            [alias] => test_2
            [title] => Test 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [id_subpage] => 1
            [alias] => test_3
            [title] => Test 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [id_subpage] => 3
            [alias] => test_4
            [title] => Test 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [id_subpage] => 3
            [alias] => test_5
            [title] => Test 5
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [id_subpage] => 5
            [alias] => test_6
            [title] => Test 6
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [id_subpage] => 0
            [alias] => test_7
            [title] => Test 7
        )   
)
```

...and this is example for dropdown list menu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="test" href="test">Test</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="test_2">Test 2</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="test_3">Test 3 <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="test_4">Test 4</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="test_5" href="test_5">
                            Test 5
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="test_6">Test 6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="test_7">Test 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thanks, Daniel J!

**EDIT**

This is my example, but does not show right:

```
function createTree($menu, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = 0) {
    foreach ($menu as $nav) {
        $subpageID = $nav['id_subpage'];

        if ($currentParent == $subpageID) {
            $navID      = $nav['id'];
            $navTitle   = $nav['title'];
            $navAlias   = $nav['alias'];

            if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";

            if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo "</li>";
            ?>

            <li><a href="<?= url($navAlias) ?>"><?= $navTitle ?></a>

            <?php
            if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) $prevLevel = $currLevel;

            $currLevel++;
            createTree($menu, $navID, $currLevel, $prevLevel);
            $currLevel--;
        }
    }

    if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo "</li></ul>";
}

createTree($menu, 0)
```

Variable $menu is array from top...

Comment: You haven't specified any problems?

Comment: @CallanHeard I don't know how to draw html dropdown from array...

Comment: well the content contained within the elements ('Test 1', 'Test 2', etc.) should be a reference to the data stored within the array using a PHP echo.. I suggest you have a look at some PHP tutorials

Comment: @CallanHeard i have updated post...

Comment: Instead of using the word 'test' can you give some context? Also, does subpage indicate each branch of the tree?

Comment: Upstairs is the html example what i need from php array...php array is dynamical...